# Use 0 1 2 3 4 to form 9 3-digit numbers

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Use $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ to make the any of these numbers:

> $$331, 333, 435, 452, 455, 458, 461, 469, 470$$

1. You must use all $5$ digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ each exactly once. You can make multi-digit numbers out of the numbers, e.g. $120$ or $42$.
2. The square function may NOT be used. Nor may the cube, raise to a fourth power, or any other function that raises a number to a specific power. 
   You may use the ^ operation if you use a digit, for example, $[(10 + 3)^2 +4]$ is acceptable because $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ is used. However, $[(10 + 3)^2 +4+2]$ can't be used because it uses an extra $2$.
3. The integer function may NOT be used. Nor may the round, floor, ceiling, repeating or concatenation symbol, or truncate functions.
4. The square root, multi factorial, subfactorial and decimal point may NOT be used.
5. $+, -, *, /, (), \text{^}, \text{and }!$ (factorial) may be used for functions. Example: factorial may be used more than once, e.g. $(3!)!=720$ is acceptable.

From the numbers $0 \text{ ~ } 500$, those $9$ numbers above are the only ones I didn't get.

Comment: So you are allowed to change around the order of the numbers?

Comment: yes correct, changing the order of the numbers is allowed.

Comment: Can we use combination or permutation operators?

Comment: Combination yes, permutation no

Comment: How will you choose who to give the bounty to? It looks like a lot of people contributed

Comment: the bounty goes to the person, who finds the solution for 452

Comment: Does Mathematica count? ($[10](\#^2+(\#+3))\times4$). Thought probably not!

Comment: I have a bad feeling 452 is impossible, sadly.

Comment: @JonMark: your proposal using # is very creative, but I really was looking for a solution using only the symbols in 5.
It is interesting to get all numbers from 0-500 with those rules, except 452 so far. I think it is impossible to prove, that 452 cannot be represented as such. It is not only a question about all possible combinations, it is the interpretation of the symbols.
Have you tried using fraction in the binomial coefficient? Further note, a fraction in brackets has also an interpretation in quadratic reciprocity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**452**

> Using the bracket notation for the [rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials):
>
>  $(10^{(2)}+3)\times4=(10\cdot11+3)\times4=113\cdot4=452$

Comment: Do you think it's possible to actually prove it's impossible, somehow? Maybe using some size argument? Obviously it wouldn't be easy but would it be possible?

Comment: @im_so_meta_even_this_acronym; well, there's only a finite number of possibilities...

Comment: There aren't actually, factorial exists

Comment: @im_so_meta_even_this_acronym; but how is $4!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!$ going to be of use?

Comment: Well, it probably won't be  but seems hard to prove, what if that number minus 2 divided by 3!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! or something was useful? (This clearly does not work by considering prime factors, but you get the point).

Comment: @im_so_meta_even_this_acronym; but (in this case at least) $3!^a$ and $4!^b$ aren't even close to $452$.

Comment: Look, I agree with you it's unlikely a solution exists. I'm just noting it seems to be hard to prove this rigorously :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96738/discussion-between-im-so-meta-even-this-acronym-and-jonmark-perry).

Comment: @JonMark, it is the first time I hear about a rising factorial, but it is all according to the rules. I accept this as solution, well done!

Answer (score 8):

Partial Answer:

470

> $4\times(3+2)!-10 = 470$

455 (by @ThomasL)

> $(4!)^2-(3!-0!)!-1 = 455$

333 (by @ripkoops)

> $213+(0!+4)! = 333$

331 (by @ThomasL)

> $((3!)!-10)/2-4!$

Comment: I managed to get 455: (4!)^2-(3!-0!)!-1 = 576-120-1=455

Comment: 333 = 213+(0!+4)!

Comment: ThomasL, ripkoops Thanks! I've aggregated these comment answers into the answer above

Comment: 331=((3!)!-10)/2-4!

Comment: @ThomasL Awesome. I think you just solved the last one

Answer (score 4):

Interpretation of the brackets as being the binomial coefficient I was able to get four more numbers 435, 458, 461, and 469:

> $435 = \binom{30}{2}\times1^4$
>   $458 = \binom{30}{2}+4!-1$
>   $461 = \binom{31}{2}-4+0$
>   $469 = \binom{31}{2}+4+0$

Comment: two numbers are left to crack: 331 and 452

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: My original solutions were invalid, sorry for being a complete idiot.

New solution for 331:

> $\dbinom{2\cdot3!-1}{4}+0!$

Comment: well the OP doesn't say you can't use binomial...

Comment: I assumed it was ok as the OP used binomial in the post directly above mines. Just checking I didn't blatantly violate one of the rules again :)

Comment: I guess so then! I'd assumed binomial's were illegal otherwise you can get away with almost anything , but if the O says they're OK, then they must be!

Answer (score 1):

Some "almost-solutions" (with one of the digits repeated twice) for 452, the only number which remains unsolved at the time of posting (I'm posting this as ideas, because somebody may rework them):

> with 2 zeroes: $452=\binom{4!/2-0!}{3!}-10$
>  with 2 ones: $452=\binom{4!/2-1}{3!}-10$
>  with 2 threes: $452=(3!+1^0)\cdot2^{3!}+4$
>  with 2 fours: $452=\binom{10+2}{4}-43$

Answer (score 0):

## *Possible* for 452

I'm not sure whether this is allowed or not but here goes:

> $0!=1$
> $1+1=2$
> $3+2=5$
> $concat(concat(4, 5), 2)$

Comment: sorry, but concat is not allowed as already mentioned in rule 3

Comment: @ThomasL - Whoopsie! I must have missed that...

Comment: Don't worry I did this too before :P